# Having multiple AngularJS apps for one site?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, javascript-framework, angularjs-routing

I am developing a site that can be broken down to a handful of main pages. These pages can be thought as isolated from each other, except they share the session data (ie. session id and logged-in username).

Initially, I was gonna build the site as a SPA using ng-view (ie. make the pages into AngularJS views). But then, I don't see any benefits for my site to be implemented in that way. And it would require extra time and efforts to make it support SEO ([Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)).

Going with an approach that does not provide any benefits and even creates extra workload doesn't seem to be too smart. So I thought to myself, why don't I make the main pages of my site into individual AngularJS apps. The parts of the site that need to be indexed by search engines are simply the initial screens of some of those apps, so I wouldn't need to do extra work for SEO. (Note: The initial screens are rendered by the Django server with data for search engines to crawl, so they are non-blank.)

For each of the apps, it may or may not have its own set of partials, depending on the requirements on it.

Example:

```
mydomain.com/item_page/1234 (load "item" app)
mydomain.com/dashboard (load "dashboard" app)
mydomain.com/account (load "account" app and default to "tab_1" view)
mydomain.com/account#tab_1 (load "tab_1" view of "account" app)
mydomain.com/account#tab_2 (load "tab_2" view of "account" app)
mydomain.com/post_item (load "post" app)
```

This is solely my random thought and I haven't seen any AngularJS examples that are comprised of multiple AngularJS apps. I would like to know:

1. Is the multiple-AngularJS-apps for one site approach feasible? What are some caveats that I should be aware of? Are there any example site out there in the wild that's taking this approach?
2. If feasible, how do I share the session data between the apps?

**Note this post is about multiple AngularJS apps for one site, not multiple AngularJS apps on the same page.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with such approach, as long as you keep the size of downloaded JS script small enough, and ensure good caching. One of examples of such applications can be GitHub (they are not using angular, but approach is the same). When you go Issues page on GitHub, it loads an html page, common Github JS libraries and page specific JS code. Navigation and actions inside page, are handled by that single page specific script. If you go to other section (like Code) a new page with new page specific JS code will be loaded. Another example is Amazon AWS console, they even use different frameworks for different pages. (both GitHub and Amazon don't use Angular, but this approach works for any JS based framework, even for GWT).

As for sharing some session data between pages, you can embed this info directly in the page itself, using inline scripts or hidden elements. E.g. when your server is generating page, it should also generate some session information into the page. Another approach is to download session data once, and store them in local storage/session storage.